# Same mysql query radically different performance times

Tags: mysql, performance

The same query with the same data in the same database runs at .18 seconds in local environment but over 100 seconds in production environment.
The local environment is a macbook pro and the production environment is a digital ocean droplet.

Comment: Thank you for the report on your performance difference. Do you have a question? If so, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question for some tips on how to ask a good question about SQL.

Comment: Show us the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From that we may be able to explain the difference, or point to what to investigate next.